# What does "rm -rf linux" do?

Tags: command-line

I found it in a uninstallation tutorial of a program, but I want to be sure what it does before executing it.

Comment: Which tutorial was that?

Comment: It's a very specific program called OpenFOAM for scientific researchers, that is why I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- `rm` is command to remove/delete stuff.
- `-rf` is two options joined together
- `-r` for recursive removal ( typically used with directories)  - `-f` to force the action
- `linux` in this command is either a file or directory.

Therefore, this command reads `delete folder called linux`. If the command really comes from a tutorial on uninstalling an application, likely that application has files that are specific to Linux and other files specific to other OS. Some applications don't have a `.deb` package and don't have installation scripts; essential files are compressed in a zip or tar archive, and deleting the files  extracted from those archives is sufficient.  Hence why this command is suggested.

However, you may see another command, which looks similar and somewhat dangerous: `rm -rf /`.  This is intended to recursively delete everything (!) from hard drive partition where root filesystem is installed (in Windows terminology it would be "delete everything from `C:\` drive). This command might be intentionally ( maybe maliciously ) suggested to newbies or clueless users as a way to uninstall Linux, but it doesn't uninstall an operating system, technically speaking not without loss of data. Uninstalling an operating system differs from uninstalling an application.

Comment: Be brave and run `rm -rf /` after doing a back-up, just in case. You'll be surprised and probably disappointed.

Comment: @jlliagre  Yup, i know it requires additional flag, and at least on Ubuntu it prevents operating on /  The problem is that being brave here is irrelevant. I am telling people not to run it as protection from the idiots. If they go extra step to add no-preserve root flag, that's their problem then.

Comment: Okay, but as you know this precise command is harmless (which is normally the case at least on systems using less that 10 years old versions of Ubuntu and similar GNU/Linux distributions, plus BSDs, OS X and Solaris), better not stating this command is dangerous and that "you will be crying and very upset"... On the other hand, telling close commands like `rm -rf /*` would be disastrous would be a useful advice.

Comment: sure, I'll change that once i get to my laptop.  I think this topic would need a bit more detailed description. I'll ping you once the answer has been edited.

Answer (score 10):

`rm -rf linux` deletes (`unlink(2)`) the file named `linux` from the current directory (the directory from which the command is run).

If the file happens to be a directory, it removes the directory recursively (`-r`) i.e. removes everything inside that directory too.

Also it does the removal forefully (`-f`) i.e. no user confirmation is required and if the file happens to be not present, no error is shown, the exit status will be `0` always (without `-f`, an error will be shown for the non-existent file and the exit status will be `1`).

Comment: I hadn't realized that linux was a folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
rm -rf linux
```

The above command deletes "linux" recursively if it is a folder else if it is a file , it just deletes the file. This command searches for the folder / file named "linux" in the current directory. You should be very careful while handling **rm** command because if you are working as a privileged user a misstyping like **rm -rf /** this could wipe your entire *root* partion. Man pages of rm command details about the arguments and short info is as follows :

```
rm -rf

rm   Remove files (delete/unlink)

-f   --force
       ignore nonexistent files, never prompt

-r   -R, --recursive
       Remove directories and their contents recursively
```